# Connecting pi to a ion counter having rs232 port

Tags: pi-3

i having two radio modules which are connected with pi, one will be attach with computer and the other will be attach with ion counter having rs232(i am using rs232 to uart converter) i have an app which is connected with pi which is comnected with computer, i want to opperate ion counter using its windows based app wirelessly. Help me regarding its code.